# Qt Quick Controls 2: Retrieve standard value of a component

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am making a layout in QML and I want to give my Label the same padding as an ItemDelegate.

How can I get the standard padding value of an ItemDelegate?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need an instance of an `ItemDelegate`. If you don't have one, you can create one and set its `visible` property to `false`:

```
ItemDelegate {
    id: itemDelegate
    visible: false
}
```

Some of the built-in styles change as the design guidelines they're based on change, so it's not a good idea to hard-code the padding based on a style's current padding values unless you have control over that style.

In addition, each style sets a different default padding, and may also use different properties to do so. The following properties can be used to control padding, starting with the most general and ending with the most specific:

- `padding`
- `horizontalPadding` (available in Qt 5.12)
- `verticalPadding` (available in Qt 5.12)
- `leftPadding`
- `rightPadding`
- `topPadding`
- `bottomPadding`

Because of this, the only way to guarantee that you'll get the correct padding for each side of the control is to use the most specific properties:

```
Label {
    leftPadding: itemDelegate.leftPadding
    rightPadding: itemDelegate.rightPadding
    topPadding: itemDelegate.topPadding
    bottomPadding: itemDelegate.bottomPadding
}
```

Comment: This works but are there any alternatives? It is not really a very "clean" way of doing so.

Comment: You can implement your own style or copy (fork) one of the existing styles so that you know what the padding values will be. Otherwise, no, there's no alternative. What did you have in mind though?

Comment: Ok I will go with this solution then. Thank you for helping!